# and, or usage in sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

I just came across this sentence -

"Scientists have long believed that comets **and, or** a type of very primitive meteorite called carbonaceous chondrites were the sources of early Earth's volatile elements -- which include hydrogen, nitrogen, and carbon -- and possibly organic material, too."

I was wondering what does "and, or" mean here?
Does it mean either comets, or meteorite or both?

Comment: Probably means "comets and chondrites" but it's rather poorly written.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is correct; it does mean 'either or both.'  However, it's normally written with a slash instead of a comma:

> and/or

Comment: And it is even more usually (and better) written "*or*". In most such cases, "*or*" means inclusive *or* (not XOR).

Comment: Using "not XOR" in everyday writing or speeches tends to confuse people. Even XOR is rare enough to cause problems.